# how to set span count in each position in recyclerview

Tags: android

how to achieve this?

when i apply this logic

gridLayoutManager =
GridLayoutManager(this@RidesListActivity, 6)

```
    gridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
            return if (position > 11)
                1
            else
                2
        }
    }
```

so it return this

click link to check output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJDCy.png

please tell me how i can do this?

i want to achieve this

click link to check output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq901.jpg

Comment: According to your design, Liner layout with fix elements is good

Comment: but i want to achieve this in recyclerview